# How would I approach designing this Reporting Services report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

I've just been asked to write an SSRS report that displays data like so:

```
Date 1    |  Date 2   |
O | C | A | O | C | A |
1 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 6 |
```

Date 1 / 2 etc will continue for each day in a selcted date range, this will most likely be the current month, I can return this data within the stored procedure so this really shouldnt be much of an issue.

O / C / A are sub headers within each day, my main problem here is how to get O C A as sub headers within each header as shown above, and also how should I return this data from my stored procedure.

My thoughts were to return the data looking like:

Date | O | C | A

But can SSRS rearange this data into the format I need?

I assume I will need to use the matrix control as I have a variable number of columns but other than this I'm not really sure how I need to approach this problem.

Any advice would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your data in the form

Date1 | O | 1

Date1 | C | 2

Date1 | A | 5

Date2 | O | 4

Date2 | C | 5

Date2 | A | 6

from SQL-Server. Then follow the instructions from this question to build your matrix:

[Column and Row grouping in SQL Server Reporting Services 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694405/column-and-row-grouping-in-sql-server-reporting-services-2008/3699316#3699316)

Comment: Cool thanks, never tried this before should be interesting :D